# trouble installing capybara-webkit on Windows8

Tags: windows, qt, installation, capybara-webkit

I am following the tutorial:https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#gentoo-linux

and get stuck at step 11, where I get an error saying Command 'qmake -spec win32-g++ CONFIG+=test' not avalable.

I have no idea how to solve this, and I did add Qt/4.8.6/bin in the path.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent a while getting this to work.  I found that the QT environment/system variables were **not** set up correctly when QT installed. Short version: I found a problem with my Qt install: although it was in my path and qmake would run (I could do `qmake -v` and get output), *that wasn't enough.*  The variables that Qt uses for paths (e.g. QT_INSTALL_HEADERS, etc.) were not correct.  I had to run the Qt configuration program **configure.exe**.   That correctly set all of the Qt variables and all was fixed.

I figured that it must be some kind of issue on my end, since I saw that others have installed it successfully.  I went through each of the components required to verify the installation and setup -- and found the problem. I've been able to compile gems just fine using just DevKit, so suspected that it had something to do with Qt. (and it did) Here's what I did to check and verify each component:

- DevKit: made sure it was installed in the ruby versions needed, and
  verified that it worked:

  1. checked '/devkit/config.yml' to make sure it listed each of different installed ruby versions, and then
  2. re-ran the DevKit install script (`ruby dk.rb install`) to be sure that DevKit had installed the right files into each of those ruby versions.
  3. I verified that DevKit was working using the recommendation on the DevKit page [https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit]:  I installed the json gem.  It was able to build the native version so that verified that DevKit was installed and working properly.
- Qt: I downloaded the Qt files (I used 4.8.5; glad to know I can upgrade). I ran the .exe file downloaded to install them.

  1. made sure that Qt directories were in my path (see the list below).
  2. made sure that the environment variable `QMAKESPEC` was defined:`QMAKESPEC=win32-g++`
  3. made the edits to the qmake.conf file (the 'Frommel workaround') as described on https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#windows
  4. ran `qmake -version` to verify that qmake would run and to verify the version
  5. ran `qmake -query` to verify the set-up for Qt.  This is where I saw the problem with my Qt install: the paths were all wrong.
  6. ran the Qt `configure.exe` program to fully configure my Qt install. **This was the key step.**  *(I thought that the initial installation program would have configured things, but obviously it didn't.)* Running this will build *all of the demos and examples* and so takes a while.  But when it completed, all was well.
  7. ran `qmake -query` to verify that the Qt settings and been fixed and were correct.
- System path and ENV variables: the following need to be in your path:

  - [devkit dir] (ex: `C:\rubys\devkit-mingw64-32-4.7.2`)
  - [devkit dir]\mingw\bin;
  - [devkit dir]\bin;
  - [qt dir] (ex: `C:\Qt\qt-4.8.5-x86-mingw`)
  - [qt dir]\bin;
  - [ruby version]\bin (ex: `C:\rubys\ruby-2.0.0-p598-i386-mingw32\bin`)
  - [ruby version]\lib\ruby\gems\
  - define the environment (system) variable `QMAKESPEC=win32-g++`  (If you don't give qmake/Qt the specification about which  system to build for, it will look for this ENV.)

I know it's been a while since you posted your question, so hopefully you've solved it.  If not, try these steps and see if they help.